# Why won't propane come out of my nearly-new propane tank?

Tags: propane

I bought a new propane tank (http://www.homedepot.com/p/Bernzomatic-20-lb-Empty-Propane-Tank-309791/202034840) and had it filled up, then used it on two separate days to fuel a weed burner torch. Worked fine. The last use was last Sunday, just a few days ago. I went to fire up the weed burner again today and nothing came out of the tank. No gas, and no hissing sound when the valve is first opened. I can open the valve all the way and stick my nose right against the tank's outlet and I don't smell any gas coming out at all.

There's clearly propane still in there because the tank's heavy and I can both hear and feel it sloshing around if I give the tank a shake. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the tank supply valve **very slowly** and make sure the weed burner valve is closed when you do it. I mean if you think you are opening it slowly you are still opening it too fast. Some of these newer tanks have a safety feature that cuts back on flow if high flow is detected.

You may also have a tank with a defective valve, if the above method does not work, take it and exchange it for a different tank at one of those places that will trade a filled tank for an empty.

It could also be your weed burner valve, a lot of those weed burners are lame Chinese pieces of crap. Try it on an alternate appliance like a camp stove or BBQ.

Comment: I have had the same issue with grills and new tanks, if you open the tank with the burner open a little or sometimes even not at all, an internal tank cutoff stops flow.  Close the valve on the tank and wait a minute, make sure the valve on the appliance is all the way closed, then open it really slowly again.

Answer (score 4):

I had a simular issue with a griill.  i turned off valves disconnected the propane hose with the hose off i turned burner nozzles to high and depressurized the system i waited a few minutes closed all nozzles and connected propane again then slowly turned burners on and it works now

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the black screw on valve from the hose
is very tight. If it is only lightly hand tightened it may not be opening the safety valve.